# CA1051 for windows phone 7,5

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

```
public class TestDB : DataContext
{
    public TestDB (string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public Table<MyClass> TableName;
}

[Table(Name = "TableName")]
public class MyClass
{
}
```

Because field 'TestDB .TableName' is visible 
                   outside of its declaring type, change its accessibility 
                   to private and add a property, with the same accessibility 
                   as the field has currently, to provide access to it

On doing what fxcop says the value is not inserted into table instead it gives an error

Comment: What's the question? If it brokes your code just don't do it.

Comment: Use a property, not a public field.

Comment: the use of properties is not allowed in LINQ to SQL DataContext class. The only way is to violate CA1051 rule. Just obviate such rule. The code showed above works, doesn't it? hence leave it as it is.. ;-)

Comment: @HansPassant please elaborate.. do we need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @J.Steen tried not working I guess fxcop doesn't recognize this as SqlCE is new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd expect:

```
public Table<MyClass> TableName;
```

to look more like:

```
public Table<MyClass> TableName
{
    get
    {
        return GetTable<MyClass>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What was null? I could understand that in *your* code (where you had a public member that wasn't apparently initialised), but if you'd changed it, it should actually return something

Comment: if I do as fxcop says ie 
private Table<MyClass> _TableName;
public Table<MyClass> TableName{ get return _TableName; set _TableName = value;} and use TableName to enter into database it gives null reference exception

Comment: @CognitiveDesire, Then don't do that - try to do as Rowland Shaw is showing, and see what happens.

Comment: will try using 'GetTable<MyClass>'

Comment: @CognitiveDesire if this answer worked for you, you should flag it as accepted (by clicking on the hollow tick to the left of it) - this will help boost your reputation on StaxkOverflow :)